# Python tkinter, label has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have an error message saying:

```
sentences = text.count(".") + text.count("!") + text.count("?")
AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'count'
```

What can I use instead of `.count` to count items?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the `Label` object directly will not get the text of it. You'll need to do `text["text"].count` or `text.cget("text").count`. Either will extract the actual text from the label. Tkinter objects can be treated as dictionaries, where the lookup keys are their [attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#label-options). `cget` stands for "configuration get" and allows you to more safely retrieve the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because the object `text` does not implement the function `count()`.

Assuming that the `text` object you are referring to is a tkinter [`Label`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm), you need to call `count()` like this:

```
text["text"].count(string)
```

So the line you posted would look like this instead:

```
sentences = text["text"].count(".") + text["text"].count("!") + text["text"].count("?")
```

Also, I would recommend you change the variable name `text` to something else that is more descriptive to avoid confusion in the future.